# Set text in textarea with jQuery on keypress event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I don't want to set text in `<textarea>` with `$('textarea').val('text')`, I want to set it with events.

**HTML**

```
<textarea>
```

**Event Listerner**

```
$("textarea").on("keyup keydown keypress", function(e) {
  console.log("Event: %s", this.type, e.which);
});
```

**Manually typing "1" in textarea**

Result: "1" display in textarea and events are

```
Event: keydown 49
Event: keypress 49
Event: keyup 49
```

***Now trying to enter "1" in textarea with jQuery***

```
var e0 = jQuery.Event("keydown");  e0.which = 49;
var e1 = jQuery.Event("keypress"); e1.which = 49;
var e2 = jQuery.Event("keyup");    e2.which = 49;

$('textarea').trigger(e0).trigger(e1).trigger(e2);
```

**Output:** all events occur but "1" does not display in textarea.

```
Event: keydown 49
Event: keypress 49
Event: keyup 49
```

- How can I display or set text in textarea with keyevents?
- when keyevents trigger then why "1" does not display in textarea?

Example JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/np1h9c8k/3/

Comment: can you create the snippet so we can test it?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet  https://jsfiddle.net/np1h9c8k/3/

Comment: IIRC triggering a jQuery event just runs the event handler.

Comment: you forgot to call `textarea.val(1)` with each trigger. Triggering events alone isn't enough to set an input's value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine and does exactly as it should. You're only triggering events, simulating `keypress`, `keydown`, `keyup`. Those events are bound one-way, they only *receive* the event from the element, they don't *transmit* an event back to the element, and thank goodness for that.

If they did, then every time someone listened for one of these events, whatever they typed would get multiplied in the input, like this mocked up snippet

```js
$("textarea").on("keyup keydown keypress", function(e) {
  // this is the action you're expecting
  $(this).val(function() {
    return this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  })
});

function abc() {
  var e0 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e0.which = 49;
  var e1 = jQuery.Event("keypress");
  e1.which = 49;
  var e2 = jQuery.Event("keyup");
  e2.which = 49;
  $('textarea').trigger(e0).trigger(e1).trigger(e2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<Br>
<button onclick='abc()'>
 press me to enter text with JS
</button>
<Br> 1) enter manully value and check console character char
<br>
<Br>2) trying to enter same event with Jquery but event trigger but value does not disply in textarea

<Br><br>testing with number "1" its charcode is 49
```